# Recommend a review as audit review

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7623992), which was approved by three reviewers that each missed the serious problem the editor introduced by removing indentation on code, which is significant in Python, as well as only partial correction of misspelled 'i' and leaving the begging at the end in place.

Obviously the reviewers did not pay attention (assuming they were competent enough to detect the problem in the first place) and it seems to me this is an excellent test for a suggest edit audit.
Is there some way I can recommend this review to be scheduled as an audit?
Do I need a certain reputation level for that?

Comment: No, it's completely automated.

Comment: Reviews shouldn't only come from users who know the details of what they are reviewing. Yes, if they are confused or know they don't know, they should skip it. But to try and fail someone on an audit because they don't know something about a particular topic (no matter how basic) is sketchy to me. If they do approve it and someone who does know about the topic sees it, they should make a second edit.

Comment: @RyanK But note that the edit actively damaged the post. IIRC, general advice on Meta was to not edit code in questions, unless you knew *exactly* what you were doing. Precisely to prevent unintentionally harmful edits like this one.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm not saying that the editor should have edited that post. He shouldn't have. I'm saying that I shouldn't fail an edit review audit because I don't know something about a specific topic, as that edit would be ok in most other languages/topics.

Comment: @S.L.Barth The code originally had alternating empty lines, probably because the OP did not know how to mark up a code block if the editor had just removed the empty lines, selected the whole block and pressed Ctrl+K no harm would have been done. Maybe there are situation where this is not correct, but IMO that can always be done.

Comment: @RyanK I think you should not review an edit if you are not sure if that edit is correct, in that case you should skip the review. That way it can end up with someone qualified to do the review.

Comment: @Anthon I agree. I'm talking about the situation (which is what probably happened here) where you are sure the edit is correct, but in reality it isn't. If I only reviewed posts that I KNEW were 100% correct, I'd have only reviewed a handful and skipped 99% of them (given, I can't review edits yet). That's why there is a "Looks Ok" button and not something else like "Correct".

Comment: @RyanK I see your point. Maybe I have been using Python to long to **not** notice that this doesn't look ok at all.